# object file format invalid or unsuitable Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

i tried running ios 5 on my mac machine along with xcode3.2.4 but after running that(ios 5) if am trying to run  my prject in xcode3.2.4 then its thowing this error...
object file format invalid or unsuitable Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

got stuck ..any idea why this is happening?

Comment: got any clue on that ? I'm also stuck on this..

Comment: that was due to some installation problems ..so uninstalled ios5 and ios 4 then again installed xcode3.2.4 so now itz wrkng :)